# Does a brand name used as common noun like Hoover respond to change in market share made by Dyson?

Tags: expressions, nouns, trademarks, products

In the UK, electric vacuum cleaners used to be called Hoover, a product name, but Dyson is now the top brand on the UK market. Is the vacuum cleaner still called Hoover? Or is it now called Dyson?

Answer (score 2):

Language changes slowly. Over time it is possible but once a name takes hold as a generic term it is not very likely to be dislodged easily. One example is "Magic Marker". It pioneered the felt-tip marker and was very successful and widespread. It went bankrupt in 1980 but, in the U.S., is still used as a generic name. The term "sharpie" is starting to take over after 50+ years.

So vacuums might become "dysons" in a few decades especially if Hover goes out of the market.

Comment: I don't think we'll start to talk about 'dysoning' the carpet because genericisation, when it happens, almost always occurs with the name of the brand which introduced the product to a given market, not with any one which subsequently becomes the dominant provider. This is what happened with "biro" which is a mispronunciation  of the name of the inventor and first manufacturer of ball-point pens. I haven't seen a genuine Biro in sixty years: the biggest brand, in the UK at least, has been Bic for decades but people still call them "biros".

Comment: I agree. Hoover covers all vacuum cleaners, Dysons are cyclone based bagless ones. Also some obstacles to the genericisation of 'dyson' are, at least in my opinion, a historic perception that people who boast about having a Dyson are snooty arrivistes and a certain shared dislike of the public persona of James Dyson (a billionaire Brexit supporter who has extolled the UK’s potential after leaving the EU, only to turn his back on Britain and move his company’s headquarters to the other side of the world).

Comment: @BoldBen One summer in the 1990s I worked at a company that sold spare parts for vacuum cleaners, cookers, fridges, freezers, etc. The sales staff were coached to finish each call by asking if the caller needed any vacuum cleaner bags as there was a "special offer this month". If the caller said "Oh no, I've got a _Dyson_." the staff were told to counter this by saying "Does it have the medical grade filters?". This usually elicited a further order (something else to boast about, and to _other Dyson owners_!) Result! Hefty markup on these!

Comment: Dysons, apparently, are lousy at getting dog hairs off carpets.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Maybe an [Electrolux](https://outreach.buzz/top-marketing-disasters/) would do the trick...

Comment: @BoldBen, would you consider posting your comment as an answer? It brings out that what is crucial is that there is a strong tendency for a brand name to become generic when it is the name of the **first** prominent brand to introduce products of a certain kind. Once that happens, the later generations learn the word as a common name and it becomes entrenched as such. It's not just that the language changes slowly, but that the later prominence of other brands is irrelevant to what was the first brand of a particular kind of products.

Answer (score 0):

It's still called a Hoover, and we hoover the carpet. Dictionaries seem to prefer upper case H when it's a noun, but lower case h when it's a verb.

When a word is deemed no longer proprietary the process is called *genericization*. This happened to Aspirin in the US. We too use the word as shorthand for 'pain-killer'.

In the UK your vacuum flask is a thermos, ballpoint pens are usually called biros (lower case), and adhesive tape Sellotape or sellotape, though in the US they call it Scotch tape, and in Australia they used to call it Durex.

Comment: I'm Australian. I don't think I've ever heard anyone call adhesive tape "Durex". I have heard Sellotape and Scotch tape. When I was at school we called it "sticky tape" and that's what I still say.

Comment: In Britain, a machine which might also be called a "digger", or in the US a "backhoe", is very widely called a "JCB", even though the maker might be another company.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited it. We used to see posters advertising it in the '80s

Comment: There was a court case against someone lower-casing 'Biro'. As it's a registered trademark and the company brought this case early, I believe lower-casing might still be a criminal offence, at least under some jurisdictions.

Comment: Years ago, Durex was a brand of sticky tape in Oz, [the tins](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Vintage-Bear-Tape-Durex-Tape-Sticky-Tape-Tins-/164275723962) sometimes come up on Ebay, so was Bear Brand (and Scotch of course). Use of Durex as a generic term for adhesive tape has declined markedly in Australia in recent years as the brand is no longer sold there, and in fact the condom brand is widely available and marketed in that country (though Durex is still rare as a generic term for condoms in Australia).

Comment: This is hurting my head so much I need to take an aspirin!

Comment: I've found a claim that there is another term for genericisation: '**Inductive Antonomasia** ...
When a specific term like _aspirin_ becomes used generically, this process is called inductive antonomasia. Aspirin is often used generically for a pain killer, just as hoover is used for any machine that cleans carpets. It is a form of metonymy.' [[UsingEnglish.com](https://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/inductive-antonomasia.html)]

Answer (score 0):

With encouragement from JSW29 I'm converting my comment from a ouple of days ago to an answer.

I don't believe we'll ever start to talk about 'dysoning' the carpet because genericisation, when it happens, almost always occurs with the name of the brand which introduced the product to a given market, not with any one which subsequently becomes the dominant provider.

This is what happened with "biro" which is a mispronunciation of the name of the Hungarian brothers, Lazlo and Gyorgy Biro who invented the first ball-point pens with sticky ink as we now have them in the 1930s. 'Biro' pens were eventually adopted by the RAF and US airforces for use in aircraft and, after the war, were introduced to the civilian market by the BIC company which became the primary manufacturer of ballpoint pens in the 1950s and then continued ever since. However they were known as 'Biro' pens in the UK in the 1950s and 'biro' has become the generalisation.

I haven't seen a pen marketed as a 'Biro' in at least sixty years: the biggest brand has been BIC for decades and there are many other makes (often unbranded) but people still call them 'biros'. Even PaperMates are sometimes referred to as biros.

The history of the ball point pen is quite interesting and [this website](https://theballpointpens.com/who-invented-the-ballpoint-pen/) gives many details. It's worth a look.